# Can't use latest versions of RProvider: Initialization of R.NET failed

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

Encountered quite a strange behaviour from RProvider:

The latest version of RDotNet by itself works just fine.
Older versions of RProvider (up to 1.1.15) also don't produce any problems.
But any recent version (from 1.1.17 to to the newest 1.1.22) throws the following error: "Initialization of R.NET failed" (even without importing the RProvider module). Moreover, the first line of the code is highlighted in red with the following warning: ("Referenced assembly RProvider.dll has assembly level attribute TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute but no public type provider classes were found").
Digging into the problem I found that the RProvider log complains about missing R.dll (which is present, of course).

```
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] initAndGenerate: starting
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] Starting server 'C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\RProvider.Server.exe' with arguments 'RInteropServer_10260_14366875_1958578678 "C:\Users\Vat\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp38A0.tmp"' (exists=true)
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Starting 'RProvider.Server' with arguments '[|"RInteropServer_10260_14366875_1958578678";
"C:\Users\Vat\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp38A0.tmp"|]'
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Registering RInteropServer at channel 'RInteropServer_10260_14366875_1958578678'
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Ready for connections..
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] Attempting to connect via IPC
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] Got some server
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Attempting resolution for 'RDotNet, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Waiting for parent process pid=10260 (System.Diagnostics.Process (devenv))
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Server started, running event loop
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] server event loop: starting
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Probing locations: C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\R.NET.1.7.0\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\R.NET.FSharp.1.7.0\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\DynamicInterop.0.8.1\lib\netstandard1.2;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.6.2\lib\net45
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Found assembly, checking version! (C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\R.NET.1.7.0\lib\net40\RDotNet.dll)
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] ...version matches, returning!
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Attempting resolution for 'DynamicInterop, Version=0.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Probing locations: C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\R.NET.1.7.0\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\R.NET.FSharp.1.7.0\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\DynamicInterop.0.8.1\lib\netstandard1.2;C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.6.2\lib\net45
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Found assembly, checking version! (C:\Users\Vat\source\repos\RTest\packages\RProvider.1.1.22\lib\net40\..\..\..\..\packages\DynamicInterop.0.8.1\lib\netstandard1.2\DynamicInterop.dll)
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] ...version matches, returning!
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] findRHomePath
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] getRLocation
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] findRHomePath: file='C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\R.dll'
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] generateTypes: getting packages
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:5, Apid:1] Adding work item to queue
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] server event loop: got work item
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] eval(.packages(all.available=T))
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating and initializing instance (sizeof<IntPtr>=8)
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating instance failed:
System.Exception: This 64-bit process failed to load the library C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\R.dll. Native error message is 'The system cannot find the file specified'
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll.ThrowFailedLibraryLoad(String dllFullName, String nativeError)
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll..ctor(String dllName)
 at RDotNet.REngine..ctor(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.CreateInstance(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
 at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Output: 
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:9292, Tid:1, Apid:1] Operation failed:
System.Exception: Initialization of R.NET failed ---> System.Exception: This 64-bit process failed to load the library C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\R.dll. Native error message is 'The system cannot find the file specified'
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll.ThrowFailedLibraryLoad(String dllFullName, String nativeError)
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll..ctor(String dllName)
 at RDotNet.REngine..ctor(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.CreateInstance(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
 at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 137
 at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
 at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
 at RProvider.RInteropInternal.eval@292.Invoke(Unit unitVar0) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 293
 at RProvider.Internal.Logging.logWithOutput[a](CharacterDeviceInterceptor characterDevice, FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\Logging.fs:line 57
[07.04.2019 0:49:22] [Pid:10260, Tid:19, Apid:1] RProvider constructor failed: System.Exception: Initialization of R.NET failed ---> System.Exception: This 64-bit process failed to load the library C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\R.dll. Native error message is 'The system cannot find the file specified'
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll.ThrowFailedLibraryLoad(String dllFullName, String nativeError)
 at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll..ctor(String dllName)
 at RDotNet.REngine..ctor(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.CreateInstance(String id, String dll)
 at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
 at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
 at RProvider.Server.EventLoop.runServerCommandSafe[a](FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\RInteropServer.fs:line 63
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
 at RProvider.Internal.IRInteropServer.GetPackages()
 at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.generateTypes@26-2.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 27
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.generateTypes@24-1.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 25
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at RProvider.RInteropClient.withServer[a](FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RInteropClient.fs:line 121
 at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.initAndGenerate@104.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 109
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
 at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at RProvider.RProvider.buildTypes() in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RProvider.fs:line 33
```

Any suggestion? Because I would really hate to use dated libraries in critical code.

So when I tried using exactly the same version of RDotNet (1.7.0) which is a dependency of RProvider 1.1.22 there weren't any problems if I tried initializing it like this:

`engine = REngine.GetInstance()`

But if I specified the path directly the program crashed out with the following exception "This 32-bit process failed to load the library C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x86\R.dll. Native error message is 'The system cannot find the file specified". Still works fine if I use the 32-bit version of R.dll (bin\i386\R.dll).

`let engine = REngine.GetInstance(@"C:\Dev\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x86\R.dll")`

At the same time RProvider 1.1.22 stubbornly attempts to link to the x64 version of R.dll no matter what architecture I choose.

Comment: Can you share a larger part of the error log file with more info around this line?

Comment: Sure, I've posted the whole file.

Comment: Thanks! This is strange - I really don't think there were any breaking changes in R provider itself (especially in the loading code) - aside from upgrade of the R.NET dependency, so it's really strage that latest R.NET works, but RProvider does not.

Comment: When you use R.NET directly, how do you initialize it? Could you try giving it the file name (reported in the log) as an argument explicitly, as in: https://github.com/fslaborg/RProvider/blob/master/src/RProvider/RInit.fs#L131

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I'm really not sure what's going on - but I think the RProvider process is running as 64 bit process (it prints `Creating and initializing instance (sizeof<IntPtr>=8)` in the log), which is why it attempts to load 64 bit version of R (to give it as much memory as possible). Can you try running your test project as 64 bit?

Comment: Another idea would be to force R provider to run as 32 bit. You should be able to do this using `corflags /32BIT+ RProvider.Server.exe` (in the `RProvider/lib/net40` folder). It should then print `sizeof<IntPtr>=4` and try to load 32 bit version of R - hopefuly helping us to figure out what's going on!

Comment: Tried running the project explicitly as 32 bit and 64 bit, no effect whatsoever. But changing corflags did the trick: as you predicted, this way RProvider loads 32 bit version of R.dll. Also tried installing different versions of R, but still can't get the 64-bit version of R working with RProvider. Oh, well, it seems I will have to content myself with the 32 bit version.

PS: You're one of the main authors of RProvider, right? Many thanks for this amazing library, it makes working with R much much easier than in other languages.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on GitHub - if it's not some strange quirk that happens just on your machine, we should look into that! (Glad the corflags trick is a usable workaround.) I didn't write the first version, but did quite a lot of tweaking and debugging (so I know how painful debugging this is!)

Comment: I assume it would be better to open an issue in the RDotNet thread? The problem seems to originate there.